# How to save changes when App gets killed?

Tags: flutter

Is there a lifeclye method that's getting called, when the user or the os kills the app?
Because I want to save changes made by the user in case the app is getting killed. But how can I achieve that?
I tried putting the save method into dispose() and into didChangeAppLifecycleState(), but the methods are not getting called, when killing the app.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print('dispose');
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    save();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      print('paused');
      save();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to save changes on didChangeAppLifecycleState calling when state is AppLifecycleState.detached